# Microsoft Bot Emulator not showing messages visually

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, emulation, bot-emulator

I am using the latest Microsoft Bot Emulator 4.10.0 on Windows 10 (2004) and tried to connect to a locally running bot as well as one that was deployed online. In both cases, my messages reach the bot and the bot's response reaches the emulator as indicated in the screenshot below.

However, the bot responses do not get rendered into the conversation window on the left. I have ensured that this is not a case of malformed JSON and that the response is plain text. Even the welcome message reaches the bot but does not get rendered in the visual conversation pipeline.

This is the first time I have seen the emulator behave this way. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific about which version of the emulator are you using?

Comment: can you upgrade it to [4.10.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v4.10.0) and give it a try?

Comment: @ranusharao, my mistake. I had typed it wrong. My version already is 4.10.0.

Comment: have you tried testing with a different bot? you can use [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) and try locally debugging the bot on other channels to ensure that the bot is working as expected.

Comment: I did test my local bot on emulator 4.10.0 and it responds as expected except that the timestamps do not show up(which was fixed in 4.11.0). You can also try downloading 4.11.0 and see if the bot responses get rendered in the conversation window.